# convert row to column in spark

Tags: sql, apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I have a date like below :- I have to display `year_month` column column wise. How should I use this, I am new to spark.

```
scala> spark.sql("""select sum(actual_calls_count),year_month from ph_com_b_gbl_dice.dm_rep_customer_call group by year_month""")
res0: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [sum(actual_calls_count): bigint, year_month: string]

scala> res0.show
+-----------------------+----------+
|sum(actual_calls_count)|year_month|
+-----------------------+----------+
|                      1|   2019-10|
|                   3693|   2018-10|
|                      7|   2019-11|
|                     32|   2017-10|
|                     94|   2019-03|
|                  10527|   2018-06|
|                   4774|   2017-05|
|                   1279|   2017-11|
|                 331982|   2018-03|
|                 315767|   2018-02|
|                   7097|   2017-03|
|                      8|   2017-08|
|                      3|   2019-07|
|                   3136|   2017-06|
|                   6088|   2017-02|
|                   6344|   2017-04|
|                 223426|   2018-05|
|                   9819|   2018-08|
|                      1|   2017-07|
|                     68|   2019-05|
+-----------------------+----------+
only showing top 20 rows
```

My output should be like this :-

```
sum(actual_calls_count)|year_month1 | year_month2 | year_month3 and so on..
```

Comment: it will be easy if you provide expected output with data.

Comment: you can use pivot on spark dataframe

Answer (score 1):

```
scala> df.groupBy(lit(1)).pivot(col("year_month")).agg(concat_ws("",collect_list(col("sum")))).drop("1").show(false)
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|2017-02|2017-03|2017-04|2017-05|2017-06|2017-07|2017-08|2017-10|2017-11|2018-02|2018-03|2018-05|2018-06|2018-08|2018-10|2019-03|2019-05|2019-07|2019-10|2019-11|
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|6088   |7097   |6344   |4774   |3136   |1      |8      |32     |1279   |315767 |331982 |223426 |10527  |9819   |3693   |94     |68     |3      |1      |7      |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

Comment: I have tried using below code :- is that similar as yours ?

Comment: val a = spark.sql("""select sum(actual_calls_count) as actual_calls_count,call_portfolio_tier,year_month from ph_com_b_gbl_dice.dm_rep_customer_call group by year_month,call_portfolio_tier""")
                                                                                                                               
 val pivotDF = a.groupBy("call_portfolio_tier").pivot("year_month").sum("actual_calls_count")
pivotDF.show()

Comment: I didn't understand your logic behind using this - .agg(concat_ws("",collect_list(col("sum")))).drop("1")

Comment: @SanskarSuman most logic are same , do just little change as val pivotDF = a.groupBy("call_portfolio_tier").pivot("year_month").agg(sum("actual_calls_count"))

Comment: @SanskarSuman  I have used agg(concat_ws("",collect_list(col("sum")))).drop("1") , actually what I am doing, I am inserting one column with constant value "1" so that I can group by complete dataframe. on that grouping I am collecting all corresponding sum using collect_list which return list of char that I am converting into string using concat_ws() and finally dropping new added column